# Magento - "created_at" field does not set automatically with the rest of the data

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise

I have created a module which saves some data into the custom tables. Both tables have "created_at" and "updated_at" fields in them. But when I save the data into any if these tables "created_at" field does not set automatically.

Here is my code:
**Sql script:**

```
->addColumn('created_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
        'nullable' => true,
    ), 'Created At')
    ->addColumn('updated_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
        'nullable' => true,
    ), 'Updated At')
```

**Model.php**

```
class my_Module extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
        public function addMyList($customerId, $name)
        {
            $this->setData(
                array(
                    'b2b_customer_id' => $customerId,
                    'name' => $name,
                )
            );
            $this->save();
            return;
        }
}
```

I have looked into other posts but most of them set this "created_at" filed along with the rest of the data in the function. Which is not what exactly I want because I think Magento should handle it itself.

But please let me know if I am thinking wrong or the code is wrong somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add this method to your main model and you don't care anymore about setting `created_at`. Every time you call `save` it will be set automatically.
It also handles `updated_at`.

```
protected function _beforeSave() {
    parent::_beforeSave();
    $now = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate();
    if ($this->isObjectNew()){
        $this->setCreatedAt($now);
    }
    $this->setUpdatedAt($now);
    return $this;
}
```